# Раскодировка ответа с кириллицей Python

Tags: python

Час добрый
Собирая информацию с одного сайта, наткнулся на проблему, что кириллица передается в юникод кодировке (проверял через онлайн декодер, указало юникод - utf-8)
Сам пример полученного ответа при помощи request.get:

```
": false, "phones": {"phones": [{"city": "961", "country": "7", "number": "8763996", "comment": "\u043f\u043e \u0431\u0443\u0434\u043d\u044f\u043c \u0441 9.00 \u0434\u043e 18.00"}]}},
```

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно вытащить в читабельном виде часть с comment.

Comment: Если Вы используете Python3, а для разбора HTML пакет Beautiful Soup, то всё должно быть нормально без всяких ухищрений.

Comment: Пробуй requests.get(url).content, а не requests.get(url).text

Comment: Не нужна никакая перекодировка, это уже нормальная строка: `print("\u043f\u043e \u0431\u0443\u0434\u043d\u044f\u043c \u0441 9.00 \u0434\u043e 18.00")` выводит `по будням с 9.00 до 18.00`. Вопрос в том, через что вы выводите ответ, что у вас в таком виде выводит. Единственное предположение - вы зачем-то используете python2 вместо python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'кодировка'  # указываем правильную кодировку принудительно
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вообще, этот ответ не решает проблему, озвученную в вопросе (он решает другую проблему).